# Example of an operator whose spectrum satisfies this condition

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Give an example of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and an operator $A: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ satisfying $$\sigma \left( A \right) = \varnothing \neq \sigma \left( A^2 \right),$$
where $\sigma \left( A \right)$ denotes the spectrum of $A$.

Can't really get anywhere with this. I know that, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, $\mathcal{H}$ has to be infinite-dimensional. Then what comes to mind is looking at $\mathcal{l}^2 \left( \mathbb{R} \right)$, but that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you spoke about $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$, I deduce that your space doesn't have to be complex.

Hence, you may take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This matrix has no real eigenvalues, since
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & 1 \\
-1 & -\lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2 + 1,
$$
but
$$
A^2 =\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which has the eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to find such an operator.  Suppose that $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $A$, then 
$$
(A^2 - \lambda I) = (A - \sqrt \lambda I)(A + \sqrt \lambda I)
$$
$(A^2 - \lambda I)$ fails to be bijective, which means that one of the operators $A \pm \sqrt \lambda I$ must not be bijective, which means that the spectrum of $A$ cannot be empty.

Comment: This is not a contradiction to my answer since in order for $\sqrt{\lambda}$ to always exist, we have to work in an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @Cloudscape perhaps, but OP does mention the fundamental theorem of algebra.  It seems he's confused about what he wants.

Comment: And by the way, I was wrong. Only all polynomials of order two need to split.